# How to preserve ownership of file while transferring it to remote server to local server?

Tags: unix, rsync, scp

I have created a file, say `file.sh` on my local unix server whose user is say, `USER1`. Now when I am copying this file from my local server to a remote unix server the ownership is getting changed to `USER2`.
I have tried many permutations with `rsync` and `scp`, but nothing is working.

How can I avoid this ? I want to preserve the ownership of the file as `USER1`.

Commands used for example:-

`scp -pqr  /apps/test/scripts/cronbak.sh USER2@remoteserver:/apps/test/scripts`

`rsync -avz /apps/test/scripts/cronbak.sh USER2@remoteserver:/apps/test/scripts`

Thanks.

Comment: Just to be sure, is USER2 is the user you are using on the remote server ?

Comment: @GuyAvraham. In  local server while logging I did sudo su USER1 and then I created the file file.sh. The file was created with owner as USER1. Now while transferring it remote server as USER2 as mentioned above in commands, the ownership is getting changed to USER2 but I want to be as USER1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to preserve the ownership of the file as `USER1`, you probably have to login as `USER1`:

```
scp -pqr  /apps/test/scripts/cronbak.sh USER1@remoteserver:/apps/test/scripts
```

For sure `USER1` must be created on remoteserver